# ReferenceError: REVISION is not defined

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

While reading the JSON response

```
 "deviceInfo": {
                "SERIALNUMBER": "0815",
                "HW-REVISION": "42"
            }
```

I faced the reference error mentioned in the title while accessing `HW-REVISION`.

Please find my code below,

```
pm.test("To verify that deviceinfo hardware revision is given as expected", function(){
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.device.deviceInfo.HW-REVISION).to.eql("42");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` in `HW-REVISION` is the problem, since it is no valid char for a variable name.

`jsonData.data.device.deviceInfo.HW-REVISION` tries to extract `REVISION` from `jsonData.data.device.deviceInfo.HW`

Instead you can access the variable as following:

```
pm.expect(jsonData.data.device.deviceInfo['HW-REVISION']).to.eql("42");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to back up Tobias' great answer, I have a working solution that passes your test.

[image: Passing Test]

Comment: You’re welcome. All credit goes to Tobias though - I just think an image brings the info to life.